# Where to look first when optimizing Scala code?

Tags: scala, optimization

I currently need to optimize a Scala implementation of an algorithm which is too slow. It is implemented in a functional way, uses only values (`val`) and immutable data structures. I am at the point where I already memoized important functions (so there are a few mutable maps in my code), which made my code twice as fast and I wonder what to do next.

So, I am not looking for generic advice on software optimization (e.g. optimize your algortihm first, use a profiler, do benchmarks...) but rather for *Scala-specific or JVM-specific optimization advice*.

My question is therefore *where to look first when trying to optimize Scala code* ? What are the ***common*** language constructs or patterns that usually cause slowdowns ?

In particular, I am seeking advice on the following points :

- I read that `for(...)` constructs are slow because an anonymous class is generated *each and every* time the body of the loop is executed. Is it true ? Are there any other places where an anonymous class is generated ? (e.g. when using `map()` with an anonymous function)
- Are immutable collections *significantly* slower than mutable collections in the general
  case (especially when it comes to map structures) ?
- Are there any *significant* performance differences between Scala 2.8, 2.9 and 2.10 ?

Comment: While this is an interesting question that sould call for interesting answers, I don't think this is a good fit for stackoverflow as it is too much open-ended (see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). You might be better off posting this question on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles : Honestly, I wondered if this question was well suited for stackoverlow before posting it (I see it as a "borderline" question). I posted it here because I am looking for *practical* and *scala-specific* advice and not theorical and generic optimization advice. If get a fourth close vote, I will delete it and post it on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: From NE Scala 2011  https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13SAn0Ru9g77T1EInCZ-7HVbEcqIMVQstVgjZFiBB4bA/present#slide=id.i0 @nermin-serifovic

Comment: As always, the first thing to do is measure your program's actual behavior. YourKit Java Profiler, while not cheap, is very good for both CPU and RAM profiling.

Comment: Alas, this question would require a book to answer, and no such book exists.  Only a small portion of existing works (e.g. "Java Performance Tuning") is likely to be relevant.  Anyway, the question is too broad for a good answer to exist in this format, and thus isn't really appropriate for SO.

Comment: Check out this talk about JVM Performance Tuning at twitter: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/JVM-Performance-Tuning-twitter

Comment: Look at C++, I heard it's much faster

Comment: @DenisTulskiy look at assembly, I heard it rocks too ;-)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I also had to optimize a lot of Scala code in the past. The following is not meant to be a complete list, just a few practical observations that might help you:

- Yes, replacing a `for` loop by a `while` is faster, even with Scala 2.10. See the [linked talk in the comments](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13SAn0Ru9g77T1EInCZ-7HVbEcqIMVQstVgjZFiBB4bA/present#slide=id.i0) for details on that. Also, be aware that using "for filtering" (a condition following the collection you are iterating) will lead to box/unboxing of your condition, which can have a big impact on performance ([see this post for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15137509/1804173)).
- The question immutable vs. mutable is simply answered by the number of updates you have to perform and it is difficult (for me) to give a general answer here.
- So far, I did not observe significant performance differences between 2.8, 2.9 and 2.10. But clearly this depends on the problem at hand. For instance, if your algorithm makes heavy use of Range.sum, you will observe big differences (because this is now O(1) in 2.10).
- I noticed that using the corresponding Java collection instead of the Scala version can also lead to significant speed-ups (as ballpark-figure I would say in the order of 5-10%). For instance, I had the following results (displayed are runtimes) in a microbenchmark for a very specific problem (note: don't generalize from that; run your own).

  ```
  ColtBitVector          min:      0.042    avg:      0.245    max:     40.120
  JavaBitSet             min:      0.043    avg:      0.165    max:      4.306
  JavaHashSet            min:      0.191    avg:      0.716    max:     12.624
  JavaTreeSet            min:      0.313    avg:      1.428    max:     64.504
  ScalaBitSetImmutable   min:      0.380    avg:      1.675    max:     13.838
  ScalaBitSetMutable     min:      0.423    avg:      3.693    max:    457.146
  ScalaSetImmutable      min:      0.458    avg:      2.305    max:      9.998
  ScalaSetMutable        min:      0.340    avg:      1.332    max:     10.974
  ```

  The problem at hand was to calculate a simple intersection of integer sets (with very specific size and number of sets). What I want to demonstrate: choosing the right/wrong collection can have a significant impact! Again, I think that it is hard to give a general advise which of these data types to choose, since this only tells us the performance in this special intersection problem (but I did chose Java's `HashSet` in a few over cases over the alternatives). Also, note that this intersection problem does not require a mutable data type. Nevertheless, there can be performance differences even in the immutable functionality (and whereas regarding `Set` it was the mutable collection which was significantly faster, it is the immutable one for `BitSet`). Thus, depending on the situation you might want to chose a mutable collection over an immutable for maximum performance (use with care!).
- I was told that declaring a variable `private[this] var foo = ...` prevents the creation of getter/setter functions and should be faster (disclaimer: I never confirmed that in a microbenchmark).
- When dealing with generic types, defining `@specialized` version for specific types should result in a speed-up.
- Although I try to avoid generalizations, I could live with the following: Try to use native Arrays. In many of my benchmarks I just ended up using Arrays, which makes sense considering their implementation in the JVM.
- A minor point that comes to my mind: I observed differences in constructing collections either by `origCollection.toSomeCollectionName` over manual construction and construction using the companion object (i.e., `SomeCollectionName(origCollection :_*)`). In many cases the latter was significantly faster.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly the kind of advice I was looking for. I wish I could upvote your question 10 times.

Comment: @Xion345 You can start a bounty in a day or so and give it to bluenote. Done that in the past for excellent answers.

Answer (score 3):

Does your code instantiate a large number of objects when run? Scala `case` classes, for example, or chains of `map`/`flatMap`'s may result in huge numbers of "unnecessary" objects being created. This may slow down the code and impose more work on the garbage collector.

Comment: I am not saying this is the main source for slow performance, of course – just something I have run into once or twice.

Comment: Good remark, pushing on the GC often cause problems with the JVM. I don't have chains of maps and I don't use case however. I will look into my heap usage.

Comment: If you did have long chains, you could use collection views. It's listed here under 2. http://www.sumologic.com/blog/technology/3-tips-for-writing-performant-scala