# Scala for comprehension performance

Tags: performance, algorithm, scala

Why is

```
for (
  a <- 1 to 1000;
  b <- 1 to 1000 - a;
  c <- 1 to 1000 - a - b;
  if (a * a + b * b == c * c && a + b + c == 1000)
) println((a, b, c, a * b * c))
```

266 ms

slower then:

```
for (a <- 1 to 1000)
  for (b <- 1 to 1000 - a)
    for (c <- 1 to 1000 - a - b)
      if (a * a + b * b == c * c)
        if (a + b + c == 1000)
          println((a, b, c, a * b * c))
```

62 ms

If I understand correct this should be the same?

---

Solution after processing answers:

```
for (
  a <- 1 to 1000;
  b <- 1 to (1000 - a)
) {
  val c = (1000 - a - b)
  if (a * a + b * b == c * c)
    println((a, b, c, a * b * c))
}
```

9 ms

Comment: It really useful to write at least Scala version you used. At most your OS and other related info.

Comment: I'm using a windows 7 and version version 2.9.2 using eclipse with jre7.

Comment: Weird way to search for solutions--you require `a+b+c==1000` so why not just set `c = 1000 - a - b`?  (Obviously this isn't an answer to the question....)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong.

This is what happens when the condition is in the loop body:

```
// this
for(x <- coll) if(condition) doSomething
// will translate to
coll.foreach{ x => if(condition) doSomething }
```

As opposed to when the condition is in the generator itself:

```
// this
for(x <- coll if(condition)) dosomething
// will translate to
coll.withFilter(x => condition).foreach{ x => dosomething }
```

You can look into [The Scala Language Speciﬁcation 6.16](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) for more details.

Answer (score 11):

You may want to check [this presentation (slides 13-15)](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13SAn0Ru9g77T1EInCZ-7HVbEcqIMVQstVgjZFiBB4bA/present#slide=id.i92) for details on how for loops are translated internally.

The main difference of your examples are:

- condition in for loop body (2. example)
- condition within the *generator* (1. example)

The latter, also referred to as *for loop filtering* comes with a performance drawback by design. To extremely simplify what is happening: Within `withFilter` (which is the first step of the translation) an anonymous new function of type `Function2[Object, Boolean]` is created (which is used to evaluate the condition). The parameter that is passed to its `apply` function must be boxed, since it is defined based on `Object`. This boxing/unboxing is much slower than evaluating the `if` condition directly within the for loop body, which allows to access variables directly.

Comment: Those slides are very interesting even found a better solution :)

Comment: @Downvoter: Would you mind to explain what is wrong with my answer?