# Scala vs Java performance (HashSet and bigram generation)

Tags: java, performance, scala

I ran into some performance discrepancy between, almost identical, implementations of Scala and Java versions.  I am seeing Java version that is 68% faster than Scala version.  Any idea as to why this happens?

Java version:

```
public class Util {
public static Set < String > toBigramsJava(String s1) {
    Set <String> nx = new HashSet <String> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length() - 1; i++) {
        char x1 = s1.charAt(i);
        char x2 = s1.charAt(i + 1);
        String tmp = "" + x1 + x2;
        nx.add(tmp);
    }
    return nx;
}
```

}

Scala version:

```
object Util {
def toBigramsScala(str: String): scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = {
    val hash: scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[String]()
    for (i <-0 to str.length - 2) {
        val x1 = str.charAt(i)
        val x2 = str.charAt(i + 1)
        val tmp = "" + x1 + x2
        hash.add(tmp)
    }
    return hash
}
```

}

Test Results:

`scala> Util.time(for(i<-1 to 1000000) {Util.toBigramsScala("test test abc de")})
17:00:05.034 [info] Something took: 1985ms`

`Util.time(for(i<-1 to 1000000) {Util.toBigramsJava("test test abc de")})
17:01:51.597 [info] Something took: 623ms`

System:

I ran this on Ubuntu 14.04, with 4 cores and 8Gig RAM. Java version 1.7.0_45, Scala version 2.10.2.

There is some more info on my [blog](http://www.mentful.com/2014/08/31/generating-bigrams-performance-scala-vs-java/).

Comment: This isn't a question though... You could revise it into a matching set of question and answer.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the byte code to see the difference.

Comment: Could it be an optimization of Java `for` loops that doesn't exist in Scala, since they have some particularities in Scala ? Those two methods seem really identical. Also, what happens if you replace the scala.collection.mutable.HashSet with a java.util.HashSet ?

Comment: You can try to swap the `for` with a `while`, I've seen loop optimizations only reliably work for `while` loops (was a few version ago though).

Comment: You might be interested by this post I just found. It seems that the for loop is indeed the problem : http://ochafik.com/blog/?p=806

Comment: @Dici I tried the while loop as the blogger recommended, it was bit faster but still slower than the Java version.

Comment: It might be the concatenation of the String, in Java version the compiler probably is changing the `+` with a StringBuilder. Check the byte code with `javap` (dissasembler) to see what is executed (interpreted).

Comment: For what it's worth, I just did a quick micro-benchmark of the `add` methods of `util.HashSet` and `mutable.HashSet`. Adding either one string or 100 different strings, I had about the same performance for both. So at east I don't think it's the fault of Scala's mutable HashSet. FYI, I based my benchmark on [this example](http://www.decodified.com/scala/2011/04/19/microbenchmarking-scala-code), which uses Caliper to avoid the usual pitfalls of micro-benchmarks on the JVM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've got roughly the same results with this scala version

```
object Util {
  def toBigramsScala(str: String) = {
    val hash = scala.collection.mutable.Set.empty[String]
    var i: Int = 0
    while (i <  str.length - 1) {
      val x1 = str.charAt(i)
      val x2 = str.charAt(i + 1)
      val tmp = new StringBuilder().append(x1).append(x2).toString()
      hash.add(tmp)
      i += 1
    }
    hash
  }
}
```

As I remember for loop in scala implemented as call to apply() method on Function0 which is megamorphic method call (expensive from JVM/JIT point of view). Plus possibly some string concatenation optimization made by javac.

I didn't check my assumptions with looking to generated byte code, but replacing for with while 
and string concatenation with StringBuilder made difference negligible.

```
Time for Java Version: 451 millis
Time for Scala Version: 589 millis
```

Answer (score 4):

For-comprehensions are always slower then using a `while` loop or tail recursion as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137360/scala-for-comprehension-performance).

The other problem in your example is the concatenation of the `String`s. Scala will use the `scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder` which has some performance issues (e.g. it will box your `char`s to `Char` instances) as mentioned in the other answers.

Changing the for-comprehension to a tail-recursive method and using `java.lang.StringBuilder` you will get mostly the same results in both Scala and Java (on my machine Scala is actually a few milliseconds faster).

Answer (score 3):

I've conducted a similar test.

Here are the classes:

Java

```
public class JavaApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = args[0];
        java.util.Set <String> nx = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length() - 1; i++) {
            char x1 = s1.charAt(i);
            char x2 = s1.charAt(i + 1);
            String tmp = "" + x1 + x2;
            nx.add(tmp);
        }
        System.out.println(nx.toString());
    }
}
```

Scala

```
object ScalaApp {
    def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
        var s1 = args(0)
        val hash: scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[String]()
        for (i <-0 to s1.length - 2) {
            val x1 = s1.charAt(i)
            val x2 = s1.charAt(i + 1)
            val tmp = "" + x1 + x2
            hash.add(tmp)
        }
        println(hash.toString())
    }
}
```

Compilers and runtime version

`Javac` javac 1.8.0_20-ea

`Java` java version "1.8.0_20-ea"

`Scalac` Scala compiler version 2.11.0 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

`Scala` Scala code runner version 2.11.0 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

Scala is also slower. Taking a look at `Scala` version, it creates two anonymous classes.

One thing that might be taking some time as well is an `auto boxing` on the `char` variable in the `for` loop.

```
  44: iload_2
  45: invokestatic  #61                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToCharacter:(C)Ljava/lang/Character;
  48: invokevirtual #55                 // Method scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder;
  51: iload_3
  52: invokestatic  #61                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToCharacter:(C)Ljava/lang/Character;
  55: invokevirtual #55                 // Method scala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/StringBuilder;
```

But that doesn't explain it all.

Answer (score 1):

There a few ways to further speed up the Scala code.

1. Instead of using a StringBuilder, we instead use a 2 character char array
2. Instead of creating temporary vals x1 and x2, we just write directly to the char array
3. We then use String's char[] constructor to create the string to place inside the HashSet
4. We extract the loop termination into a variable max, just in case the JIT would miss optimizing that.

   ```
      object Util {
        def toBigramsScala(str: String) = {
          val hash = scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.empty[String]
          val charArray = new Array[Char](2)
          var i = 0
          val max = str.length - 1
          while (i < max) {
            charArray(0) = str.charAt(i)
            charArray(1) = str.charAt(i + 1)
            hash.add(new String(charArray))
            i += 1
          }
          hash
        }
      }
   ```

With those changes, I was able to get the same run time between the Java and Scala code.  Surprisingly (at least in this example), the java.util.HashSet didn't give any performance gain over mutable.HashSet.  In fairness, we can also apply all these optimizations to the Java code as well,